# How to Clear Latitude and Longitude Value in Android, When Application is Closed

Tags: android, location, listener

Sorry for my bad English.

Just like what I asked. I have this class to handle location change.

```
package com.mousepad.runningkids.util;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyLocationManager {

    private Context context;
    private double myLat = 0.0;
    private double myLon = 0.0;
    private LocationManager locationManager = null;
    private Location location = null;
    private Criteria criteria;
    private String locationName = null;
    private MyLocationListener mll;

    public MyLocationManager(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    private String setCriteria() {
        this.criteria = new Criteria();
        this.criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        this.criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        this.criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        this.criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        this.criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        return locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    }

    public double getMyLatitude() {
        return this.myLat;
    }

    public double getMyLongitude() {
        return this.myLon;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return this.locationName;
    }

    public void onLocationUpdate() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        String provider = setCriteria();

        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        updateWithNewLocation(location);
        mll = new MyLocationListener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0, mll);

    }

    public void stopLocationListenerService() {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this.mll);
    }

    private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            this.myLat = location.getLatitude();
            this.myLon = location.getLongitude();
            // Toast.makeText(this.context,
            // "Lokasi Anda:\n" + this.myLat + "\n" + this.myLon,
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            getLocationName(this.myLat, this.myLon);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "Lokasi Anda Tidak Diketahui",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void getLocationName(double lat, double lon) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> adresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (adresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = adresses.get(0);
                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                    sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                sb.append(address.getCountryName()).append("\n");
            }
            this.locationName = sb.toString();
            // Toast.makeText(context, sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myLat = newLocation.getLatitude();
            myLon = newLocation.getLongitude();
            getLocationName(myLat, myLon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    }

}
```

When this application is closed, the last Latitude & Longitude, is still saved, and When I run it again, the last location that have been saved in the phone is the last location, until it listen, and update it's location.

My question is how to clear location (spatial) data like latitude & longitude without turning off the phone. Does it's saved on application cache ? Because I already create a code to clear the cache when the apps is closed.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add Two Method like below in MyLocationManager  which will clear you lat and long value when you Activity Class's onPause Method call.

```
  public  setMyLatitude(double paramLat) {
       this.myLat=paramLat;
  }

public  setMyLongitude(double paramLong) {
     this.myLon=paramLong;
}
```

Now Call this set Method when your Application is closing  ,that means

```
 @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 //Call Set Method from Here ,set them to initial Value     
      super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could start location manager in onResume() and could remove location listener in onPause(), so next time you start activity you will get your current position because onResume() it will call onLocationChanged() and you will get new postition or wat you can do is onResume() use predefined geopoint. Or other way is like this.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        if (checkGPSservice() /*this is just of my use you dont need if block just write following line*/) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
```